# What are the methods for extracting raw GA4 data no row limits?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are interested in downloading raw (non-aggregated) GA4 data.

I'm aware of [4 methods](https://analyticscanvas.com/4-ways-to-export-ga4-data/) for extracting GA4 data:

1. Reports
2. Explorations
3. Analytics Data API
4. BigQuery Export

The only method that I know of that returns raw GA4 data with no row limits is the BigQuery Export.

**Are there any other methods that return raw GA4 data no row limits?**